# Plotting a tree timeline (evolution history)

Tags: tree, data-visualization, timeline

I am currently writing a literature review, and I'd like to be able to plot the evolution of some of the algorithms by plotting papers I've read, and their connections via citation as a horizontal tree, and have the x-axis correspond to publication date.

Here is an example of what I am looking for.
[image: Linux Distribution timeline]

### Questions

- What is this type of graph called?
- Are there existing tools or examples to produce this type of graph?

Ideally, I'd like to achieve this in R, or using D3.js, but I am flexible.

*Note: cross-post from [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/171715/plotting-a-tree-timeline-evolution-history)*

Comment: Your example is a nice one. Here's another: https://www.edureka.co/blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/Evolution-of-Linux-Shells-Types-of-Shells-in-Linux-Edureka.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The type of visualisation you are after is called a 'cladogram', used in cladistics, or the classification of organisms based on shared characteristics. Other similar visualisations that apply further categorisations are called 'phylograms' or 'phylogenetic trees.'

After a quick google I located [this R package](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/ggtree/inst/doc/ggtree.html), `ggtree`, which seems to do what you want (branching tree and potential for labelled x-axis and even y-axis if you need). It also appears that this package allows for highly customisable plots. Good luck!

Comment: Great! The name for this type of graph has been bugging me. Cladogram :)